# Connections between conformal field theory and particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, conformal-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, ads-cft

I'm wondering if one could use conformal field theory to predict any facts in (experimental) particle physics?

I think CFT shares some similarities with QCD, but I'm not sure if one could use CFT to predict any effects in QCD.

Comment: Conformal field theory is more or less a "tool" in my understanding. The fields which are conformal invariant, the symmetry can be exploited to calculate  two point function, three point function... exactly.

Comment: afaik CFT is a field theoretical tool, QCD is a theory that describes the strong force, as QED is a theory that describes the electromagnetic force. Do you mean **use** CFT to model QCD?

Comment: @annav yes yes, I'm wondering if CFT model QCD

Comment: At the moment QCD is modeled by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD . Because the coupling constant is so large is is not possible to use pertubation theory, afaik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should clarify, what do you mean by predicting facts in QCD by means of CFT. CFT studies the correlation functions, relationships between them by means of conformal bootstrap. QCD is not a conformal theory even if we are dealing with negligible masses of fermions, due to the existence of scale - $\Lambda_{QCD}$.

The theories experiencing continious phase transitions are conformal for the critical temperature $T = T_c$. However, for QCD for zero chemical potential there is no phase transition with the increase of temperature, but a crossover at the temperature $T \sim 150$ MeV. With the inclusion of chemical potential at a certain magnitude, there emerges the line of phase transition. And at the value, where this line begins, there is presumably critical point, where the transition is of second order, where the CFT might find applications.

Also, maybe you have meant the $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM theory, which is conformal (superconformal) which is definitely described in terms of CFT, and it, indeed, shares some common properties with QCD.

Comment: thanks! I'm just wondering why for zero chemical potential there will be no phase transition? Is non zero chemical potential a necessary condition for phase transition?

Comment: @fenglin the absence of the phase transition at zero chemical potential follows from the fact, that unlike the pure Yang-Mills theory, there is no order parameter such a area fall-off of Wilson loops, because when separating the charges on large enough distances the string between them breaks. The mechanism, how chemical potential leads to the emergence of phase transition line, as far as i know, is still not understood. We have so far experimental and lattice QCD evidence.